# UITableView segue within the same ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have a UIViewController that contains both, a map and a tableView which are connected together and it looks something like this:

[image]

And I'd like to be able to push the tableView to another tableView within the same view controller so that the map stays where is it. Of course I'd like to be able to unwind the segue backwards programmatically with a button that'll appear in the navbaritem in the top left.

Similar behaviour can be observed in the iPad tableView controllers placed in a popover. How would I go about doing this in Swift (iOS 8) ?

Any code snippets or pointers to existing code examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For this type of situation you can use view controller containment. In storyboard you can drag a "Container View" object into the space and add a navigation controller to it then you can do regular navigation controller things. You can also do it in code by simply adding a navigationController's view as a subview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve view controller containment like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Setup the container view
        _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: // DESIRED FRAME];
        _containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:_containerView];

        // Setup the main view controller
        [self addChildViewController:_mainViewController];
        _mainViewController.view.frame = _containerView.bounds;
        [_containerView addSubview:_mainViewController.view];
        [_mainViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Now you can create both table views in separate view controllers. It sounds like you should add a navigation controller ("mainViewController" in code snippet) to your main view controller so you can "push" a new table onto the stack.

Comment: Cheers, mate. I got your logic despite the fact I wanted it in Swift :)

Comment: Whoops sorry missed the Swift part :) Glad I could be of service :)

Answer (score 0):

This technically is not a "push" -- when the user selects a cell on your tableview, triggering a call to the tableview delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

...you should bring in a second table view from the right side of the screen.

Each of your tableview datasource and delegate methods should look distinguish between the first and second tableview. Here's an example for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        return self.collection1.count
    } else if tableView == self.tableView2 {
        return self.collection2.count
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If his two tables have data that is fairly different it is cleaner to create both tables in separate view controllers and use view controller containment to achieve what he wants.

Comment: true. your turn to post an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Basic UIView Animation to show the seconds table moving from left side of screen on didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the first table