# How to push to a different UITableView within the same ViewController and navigate back to first UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Tab Bar Controller setup. When the user selects a tab, it takes them to a `UIViewController`. Currently I have a `UITableView` setup in this View Controller. What I would like to do is, upon selecting a cell from TableView1, I'd like to have a "push" effect where TableView2 comes in from the right side of the screen, and take over.

I've found the following question, similar to mine:
[UITableView segue within the same ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705530/uitableview-segue-within-the-same-viewcontroller)

One of the suggestion is exactly what I want to achieve, however I could not get it to have that slide effect.

What I've done is added two `UITableViews`, then `tableView1.hidden = true` in viewDidLoad.

Then in code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!

        if tableView == tableView1
        {
            // Dequeue the cell to load data
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
           ....
        }
        else if tableView == tableView2
        {
            // Dequeue the cell to load data
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
          ....
        }

        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if tableView == tableView1
        {
            tableView2.hidden = false
            tableView1.hidden = true
            playlistVideosTableView.reloadData()
            // Deselects the row
            tableView1.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

However, it doesn't have that "slide effect" and makes the tableview appears instant.

I could make another `UIViewController` with the second tableview but I don't want to make my Tab Bar disappear.

How can I achieve this, and how can I ensure the ensure gets back to the first UITableView?

Thanks

Comment: I  think we don't have that delegate method available in UITableView , Actually Controller Class having these type of functionality not a UIView child class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to simply create another UIViewController that has a UITableView, so preferably a UITableViewController.

Then in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` you call a segue to the new ViewController. This will give you the desired effect and is a cleaner solution as well.

You will not lose your TabBar either with this solution if you embed all ViewControllers in this tab into a NavigationController.

EDIT: sample code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("editSpecialStage", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
}
```

And in the Storyboard you have a NavigationController as the first ViewController from the TabBar. Then the first ViewController and then the second, connected via push segue.

Comment: can you provide a sample code please? When that new ViewController become present, wouldn't I lose my Tab Bar Navigation at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

> I could make another UIViewController with the second tableview but I don't want to make my Tab Bar disappear.

Why will your tab bar disappear? It wouldn't if you used a `UINavigationController`!

Just do what I say, alright?

First create that new view controller and connect the two VCs with a show segue

```
First VC -show-> Second VC
```

Now the whole picture would look like

```
Tab Bar VC -view controllers-> First VC -show-> Second VC
```

Now modify this to

```
Tab Bar VC -view controllers-> Navigation Controller -root vc-> First VC -show-> Second VC
```

Now the segue will slide the Second VC to the left and your tab bar won't disappear!

Comment: I did exactly as you said to achieve this :)